# Deploying asgi and wsgi on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, wsgi, channel

I'm trying to deploy Django Channels on Heroku using asgi alongside my existing wsgi implementation. Can I deploy both asgi and wsgi to heroku with the following setup?

My procfile:

```
web: gunicorn chatbot.wsgi --preload --log-file -
daphne: daphne chat.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --settings=chat.settings -v2
```

My asgi.py file:

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "chat.settings")

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

My wsgi.py file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "chat.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

And my channel layers in settings.py:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')]
        },
        'ROUTING': 'chat.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured this out, in case this might be relevant to anyone else. Using just asgi was the best solution. My procfile ended being:

```
web: daphne chat.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --settings=chat.settings -v2
```

As a solution for serving static files, I updated my routing.py file to include a StaticFileConsumer.

Comment: Any idea what `-v2` accomplishes?

Comment: @MichaelHays `-v2` is for verbosity. Run `python manage.py runserver --help` for more info

Comment: When I deploy my app with your Procfile, I get this error `manage.py runworker: error: the following arguments are required: channels`. Do you have any idea what I need to do?

Comment: @Anatol it might be so old but here is for those who do not know the answer `python manage.py runworker channels --settings=chat.settings -v2
 `

Comment: @Roel I am getting this error when I updated my Procfile worker to what you suggested: `ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'chat.routing'`. I have a routing.py file in my chat project with an application. Do you know why I get this error?

Comment: @Anatol This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/q/51634522/6143656

Comment: Do I need to install daphne?

What if I am not using channel layers?