# Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module while runserver using channels 2

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I have followed the channels tutorial but while running these error throw

Version of the packages is
**channels==2.1.2**
**Django==2.0.4**

**what I missed ?**
in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   "channels"
    ....
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "myapp.routing.application"
```

added file mayapp/routing.py

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter 

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
})
```

this is the error log

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
August 01, 2018 - 13:11:42
Django version 2.0.4, using settings 'myapp.local_settings'
Starting ASGI/Channels version 2.1.2 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f71ecfb6400>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 33, in get_default_application
    module = importlib.import_module(path)
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'myapp.routing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in inner_run
    application=self.get_application(options),
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/management/commands/runserver.py", line 105, in get_application
    return StaticFilesWrapper(get_default_application())
  File "/home/vkchlt0192/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 35, in get_default_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'myapp.routing'
```

Comment: Did you get solution ?

Comment: now it's working for me, I am using channels==2.1.5

Comment: my case was the syntax problem, such as `from channels.routine` which should be `from channels.routing`. and got similar error when `py manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 17):

In my case it was wrong import in different file.

What you should do is

```
python manage.py shell
from mysite.routing import application
```

Look what exact error it produces and try to fix that

Answer (score 5):

Just change

> ASGI_APPLICATION =  mysite.routing.application

to

> ASGI_APPLICATION = "routing.application"

Comment: Don't know why but this fixed the issue.

Comment: Figured it out: the problem was because I had the "routing.py" file in the "mysite/" not in the `mysite/mysite/`. Adding it there now I can use: `ASGI_APPLICATION = mysite.routing.application` in seetings file.

Answer (score 5):

Check for any potential errors (maybe import error) in consumers.py. 
Also, try to put channels as the first item in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py.

As stated in channels document:

> The Channels development server will conflict with any other third-party apps that require an overloaded or replacement runserver command. An example of such a conflict is with whitenoise.runserver_nostatic from whitenoise. In order to solve such issues, try moving channels to the top of your INSTALLED_APPS or remove the offending app altogether.

Comment: this was the solution! The above error message masks any syntax errors that occurr in that file. Very inconvenient

Answer (score 3):

This helped me:
Everything with `ASGI_APPLICATION` was fine (thanks to all the previous answers given here). But I read logs a bit further and it appeared, there was an import error somewhere else:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'channel_session_user_from_http' from 'channels.auth'`

Once I got rid of it, everything came back on track.

Comment: In my case `ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'django.conf.urls'`

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your `routing.py` file inside `mayapp/mayapp/routing.py` instead of `mayapp/routing.py`

Comment: Could you be more specific. File is actually inside the project root directory. It seems right file path !

Comment: it's on project root path,  now it is working for me after update the channel version to channels==2.1.5

Comment: @ShihabudheenKM Can you tell your channels, django and asgiref version?

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody comes along this. Remember: ASGI_APPLICATION = "myapp.routing.application" should go at the bottom of settings.py to ensure nothing get snagged in production!

mysite/myapp/routing.py

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import myapp.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

myapp/routing.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('chatroompage', consumers.ChatConsumer),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Django 2.2 doesn’t have inbuilt ASGI support so we need to use Channel’s fallback alternative. Create myproject/asgi.py like this:

```
import os

import django
from channels.http import AsgiHandler
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": AsgiHandler(),
  # Just HTTP for now. (We can add other protocols later.)
})
```

source: [Channels Docs.](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html)

Answer (score 1):

in my case there were unresolved packages in consumer.py check if you have any unresolved packages in your channels .py files

Comment: i had the same problem, if there is any error down the "asgi" line, it shows this error

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing the same problem.
Make sure:
=> The routing.py file should be inside the project root folder(i.e. django server, one that has settings.py, wsgi.py,..)
=> In settings.py include, ASGI_APPLICATION = "yourprojectrootname.routing.application"

=>Sometimes, the coding inside routing.py file may generate this error, to check if this is the case remove all the coding and enter the general template coding,

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
})
```

then run the 'python manage.py runserver'. This time if you didn't get any error then problem lies in coding inside routing.py. Debug and fix the issue.

=>In other cases this may be of version problem, downgrading to channels==2.1.2 works

Answer (score 1):

When importing your app with absolute path in myapp/routing make sure it is imported like:

import myapp.routing

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import myapp.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            myapp.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

It may give you warning as error in PyCharm but you will have working Django channels. I reported it as bug to PyCharm. I hope no one else will spend 3-4 hours on it like me)

Answer (score 1):

I have written the below code in asgi.py file, websocket_urlpatterns is imported from routing.py file. This is worked for me.

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter,URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from .routing import websocket_urlpatterns


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myApp.settings')



application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(websocket_urlpatterns))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
python3 manage.py shell
>>> from your_project import asgi
```

if you see below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/your_project/asgi.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.asgi'
```

your django version is lower than 3.x. asgi is supported after 3.x

found it from here

[Django application: No module named 'django.core.asgi'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69617994/django-application-no-module-named-django-core-asgi)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to remove channels and daphne first.

```
pip uninstall channels

pip uninstall daphne
```

Now, Install both channels and daphne together with the below command

```
python -m pip install -U channels["daphne"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same issue i did everything to resolve it, creating another virtual environment and installing older version of Django but after 2 days of hardware i came to realize that my consumers.py file was missing with just a 's' in consumer's' and after that i also corrected in my routing.py file. May be this could be your problem also please do check all the file names first.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently faced to this problem, and quickly solved it.
After checking the configurations in `settings.py` and `routing.py`, I found the problem is in this line:

`from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack`

the problem is the version compatibility. Then, I upgraded the `requirements.txt` to the below and it works quiet well.

```
channels==2.4.0
channels-redis==2.4.2
daphne==2.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put `routing.py` inside `mysite/mysite/` not `mysite/` otherwise you won't be able to use `ASGI_APPLICATION = mysite.routing.application` in the settings file and you get that error.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is course by not importing the get_asgi_application in asgi.py file in settings.py actually had the same issue when i was trying to deploy my app but was able to resolve it by importting get_asgi_application and using it as a traditional http request fallback like so in the asgi.py file :

```
mport os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from django.urls import path

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
# Initialize Django ASGI application early to ensure the AppRegistry
# is populated before importing code that may import ORM models.
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from chat.consumers import AdminChatConsumer, PublicChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Django's ASGI application to handle traditional HTTP requests
    "http": django_asgi_app,

    # WebSocket chat handler
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                path("chat/admin/", AdminChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
                path("chat/", PublicChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem by:

- python manage.py migrate
- python manage.py makemigrations
- python manage.py migrate

Also check if you have put the **routing.py** file in the wrong directory. It should be **'myproject/routing.py'**

Comment: You should put `routing.py` inside `mysite/mysite/` not `mysite/`.

Answer (score -2):

Changing define ASGI_APPLICATION variable and CHANNEL_LAYERS.default.ROUTING variable
from

```
<project_name>.routing.application
```

to

```
routing.application
```

With this, I can run properly

Answer (score -2):

### Django Version problem

---

None of the above and other stack overflow answers caused a problem to me I tried the full code from documentation using Django version 3 but without no help and the error still appearing every-time

### Solving

---

solved by downgrading Django version from version 3 to 2.2 and followed the instruction of the 2.2 version (notes section) in the documentation

---

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_1.html