# Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'myproject.routing'

Tags: python, django, django-channels, channel, asgi

I've followed the channels 2 tutorial, but I'm getting this error after running `py manage.py runserver`

```
File "C:\Users\Mach2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 35, in get_default_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module %r" % path)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module 'channels_test.routing'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the error, i was using the version 3.0.dev20190127224143 of django, and i solved doing the roll back to the version 2.1.7

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this line to **settings.py** file.

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "routing.application"
```

found here: [Cannot import ASGI_APPLICATION module while runserver using channels 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51634522/cannot-import-asgi-application-module-while-runserver-using-channels-2)

Comment: In my settings.py file i have ASGI_APPLICATION = 'channels_test.routing.application', i've tried ASGI_APPLICATION = "routing.application", but i have the same error

Comment: channels_test is your app name? Did you added the WSGI_APPLICATION setting? Also channels should come as soon as possible in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: yes, channels_test is my project name. in my settings.py i have also WSGI_APPLICATION, and channels is the first in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Did you installed channels with pip3 and are you running runserver with python 3.7? If yes, then it's a very curious problem.

Comment: yes i've installed channels with pip3 and i'm running runserver with python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

1. put the routing.py in the same level as settings.py.
2. Ensure there is no error in routing.py. You can check it by replacing the content with

   from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

   application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
   })

and see if it solves.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error because i wrote consumer.py instead of consumers.py by mistake. Then I renamed it to consumers.py and error solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue because I wrote a class name in imports of `asgi.py` file that wasn't defined. Then I removed that undefined class of authentication and the error was fixed.

Please check your defined imports in `asgi.py` file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30680472)

Answer (score 0):

for myself it was beacuse of a missing package called
**whitenoise**, after installing via pip everything worked fine

> pip install whitenoise

Answer (score 0):

I solved it changing my version of Django from 4.0.5 to 3.2.5; see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/releases/3.2.5/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32083790)

Answer (score 0):

It helps to me to mark a directory as a source root in Pycharm