# Django application: No module named 'django.core.asgi'

Tags: python, django

since today I am not able to run my Django application because there is an import error:
"No module named 'django.core.asgi'"
Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Informations:

- Manjaro
- python3.9
- Django version: (2, 2, 19, 'final', 0)

My installed python moduls (requirements.txt)

```
Django
google-auth
gunicorn
Channels
Daphne
channels_redis
pyzmq
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for smartcube_interface project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '+%qo9se#w7^wrfd@845#-h59s7y-8hooxegoha31k&##91z2&p'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'chat',
    'channels',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'smarthome',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'smartcube_interface.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        "DIRS": ["smartcube_interface/templates/"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'smartcube_interface.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
        #'NAME': '/var/www/smarthome/static/database/db.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/var/www/smarthome/run/database/db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/smarthome/static"
MEDIA_ROOT = "/var/www/smarthome/media"

# mysite/settings.py
# Channels
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'smartcube_interface.asgi.application'
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

asgi.py

```
"""
ASGI config for smartcube_interface project.

It exposes the ASGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/
"""

import os

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'smartcube_interface.settings')
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter

import chat.routing
import smarthome.routing



#application = get_asgi_application()
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": django_asgi_app,
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            #chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            smarthome.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: what's the Django's version?

Comment: update your `setting.py` and `asgi.py` file

Comment: (2, 2, 19, 'final', 0)

Comment: @sunilghimire how should I update the files?

Comment: I mean to say ... edit your question and add the `setting.p` `asgi.py` code here

Comment: the Django v2 is your problem - asgi is supported in Django 3+ only

Comment: I am having this issue with Django 4.0. Not supported yet for 4?