# module not found 'core' error when deploying django with django channels on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-channels, daphne

I have been trying to deploy my application on heroku with django channels and I always get the following error

```
2022-05-26T20:09:58.137436+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

I have seen previous questions such as [Deploying asgi and wsgi on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741696/deploying-asgi-and-wsgi-on-heroku) but even when following these steps I can't get the deployment to work.

My channel layers in settings.py:

```
ASGI_APPLICATION = "server.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')]
        },
        'ROUTING': 'server.routing.channel_routing',
    }
}
```

My asgi.py:

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'core.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

My wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'server.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My Procfile

```
web: daphne server.asgi:channel_layer --port $PORT --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2
chatworker: python manage.py runworker --settings=server.settings -v2
```

My file structure

```
server
    |
    |_ _ chat
    |   |
    |   |_ __init__.py
    |   |
    |   |_ admin.py
    |   |
    |   |_ consumers.py
    |   |
    |   |_ models.py
    |   | 
    |   |_ routing.py
    |   | 
    |   |_ urls.py
    |   |
    |   |_ views.py
    |_ _ server
    |   |
    |   |_ __init__.py
    |   |
    |   |_ asgi.py.py
    |   |
    |   |_ routing.py
    |   |
    |   |_ settings.py
    |   | 
    |   |_ urls.py
    |   |
    |   |_ wsgi.py
    |
    |_ _ manage.py
    |
    |_ _ Procfile
    |
    |_ _ requirements.txt
```

My requirements.txt file:

```
aioredis==1.3.1
asgi-redis==1.1.0
asgiref==3.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
attrs==21.4.0
autobahn==22.4.2
Automat==20.2.0
cffi==1.15.0
channels==3.0.4
channels-redis==3.4.0
constantly==15.1.0
coverage==6.4
cryptography==37.0.2
daphne==3.0.2
Deprecated==1.2.13
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==4.0.4
django-cors-headers==3.12.0
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
djangorestframework==3.13.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
hiredis==2.0.0
hyperlink==21.0.0
idna==3.3
incremental==21.3.0
msgpack==1.0.3
msgpack-python==0.5.6
packaging==21.3
psycopg2==2.9.3
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycparser==2.21
PyJWT==2.4.0
pyOpenSSL==22.0.0
pyparsing==3.0.9
pytz==2022.1
redis==4.3.1
service-identity==21.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
Twisted==22.4.0
txaio==22.2.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
tzdata==2022.1
whitenoise==6.1.0
wrapt==1.14.1
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

Comment: Share your **requirements.txt** file.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the post with the requirements.txt file.